# Mysql query with single quotation mark in the where clause

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbname WHERE LCASE(title) LIKE '%l\'infinito%'
```

The value into the table contains slash before quote.
Why the query returns no results?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The escaping is correct. You actually do not need `LCASE` since `LIKE` is not case sensitive (at least not on my Linux system):

```
mysql> SELECT 'L\'Infinito' LIKE '%l\'infinito%';
+------------------------------------+
| 'L\'Infinito' LIKE '%l\'infinito%' |
+------------------------------------+
|                                  1 |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Maybe you want to search *L'Infinito*, with an 'n'. Or maybe the title *seems* to contain a single quote, but it is one of those never sufficiently damned Windows Word reverse English quotes.

Or maybe there is a space in the title after the quote. In many fonts, this is not immediately visible.

```
L' infinito
```

Can you search using '%ifinito%' (or '%infinito%'), and verify that the found row does indeed contain a single ASCII quote?

**UPDATE**

...and finally, *maybe the database is wrong*. To wit:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE catalogo (title varchar (32));
mysql> INSERT INTO catalogo VALUES ('L\'Infinito');
mysql> SELECT * FROM catalogo;
+------------+
| title      |
+------------+
| L'Infinito |
+------------+
```

If you run the same `SELECT` as before, does MySQL return *L'Infinito* without escaping? Because if you have instead

```
+-------------+
| title       |
+-------------+
| L\'Infinito |
+-------------+
```

then *the title has been saved wrong*, escaping the quote sign TWICE. So there is an escape sign between the L and the quote, and you would have to search for

```
L\\\'Infinito
```

to "neutralize" the error.

Comment: I tried

SELECT id, titolo FROM catalogo WHERE LCASE (titolo) LIKE '%\'infinito%'

deleting the character "l" from the title and I have one result ...

Comment: You may have a whitespace in the string. *Post that result!* :-)

Comment: It could be a `’` instead of a `'`.

Comment: @tadman no, he left the single quote and it worked. There must be something wicked *before* the single quote. A whitespace in the wrong place, maybe, or maybe there is a double escape *in the database*.

Comment: Ok,
I inserted as value - L'infinito - without slash, in the table

Running the query:

SELECT id,title FROM catalogo WHERE LCASE(title) LIKE '%L\'infinito%'

it works!

thank you all!

Comment: This could be a case of double-escaping when inserting. This happens when using SQL escaping incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbname WHERE LCASE(title) LIKE '%l\\\'infinito%'
```

Comment: @user1636103 Show some value of table `tbname`.

Comment: SELECT id,titolo FROM catalogo WHERE LCASE(titolo) LIKE '%l\'infinito%'

Comment: @user1636103 I mean What value does column `title` contains. (Show the value of column `title`.)

Answer (score 0):

The following query will answer your question:

```
string s="'infinito";
s=s.Replace("'", "''");
SELECT * FROM tbname WHERE LCASE(title) LIKE '%s%'
```